# function for converting a struct to map in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to convert a struct to map in Golang. It would also be nice if I could use the JSON tags as keys in the created map (otherwise defaulting to field name).

#### Edit Dec 14, 2020

Since [structs](https://github.com/fatih/structs) repo was archived, you can use [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) instead.

#### Edit TL;DR version, Jun 15, 2015

If you want the fast solution for converting a structure to map, see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589564/function-for-converting-a-struct-to-map-in-golang#25117810), upvote it and use that package.

Happy coding! :)

---

#### Original Post

So far I have this function, I am using the reflect package but I don't understand well how to use the package, please bear with me.

```
func ConvertToMap(model interface{}) bson.M {
    ret := bson.M{}

    modelReflect := reflect.ValueOf(model)

    if modelReflect.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        modelReflect = modelReflect.Elem()
    }

    modelRefType := modelReflect.Type()
    fieldsCount := modelReflect.NumField()

    var fieldData interface{}

    for i := 0; i < fieldsCount; i++ {
        field := modelReflect.Field(i)

        switch field.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            fallthrough
        case reflect.Ptr:
            fieldData = ConvertToMap(field.Interface())
        default:
            fieldData = field.Interface()
        }

        ret[modelRefType.Field(i).Name] = fieldData
    }

    return ret
}
```

Also I looked at JSON package source code, because it should contain my needed implementation (or parts of it) but don't understand too much.

Comment: Is there a particular goal you're trying to achieve here?  If you are dealing with the `mgo/bson` package (which seems possible due to the use of `bson.M`), can't it already perform a conversion from a struct similar to `encoding/json`?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge yes it already converts structure to bson representation. Also I can use bson.marshall(from struct)/unmarshall (to map) to perform the conversion. But wanted to make a function converting the struct to map directly.

Comment: It involves reflection, package [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect), and it is both slow and a royal pain to use; the `json` package is that way because using reflection is hard. My advice would be either to use something that already does the reflection parts for you (object-to-DB interfaces like `gorp` or `mgo`, builtin packages like `json`) or use (possibly repetitive) handwritten code to avoid reflection entirely. It's a situation where the approach that's natural and efficient in, say, JavaScript just isn't in Go.

Comment: @twotwotwo Ok, well I already use struct -> bson encoded -> bson decode to map. I think you gave a good lesson in understanding better what Go is. I'm coming from dynamic languages (php and js) and I'm playing with Go at the moment. I was amazed by the language and still am, but sometimes I have this feeling that I'm alone when trying to do something. Thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tonyhb/5819315 is code someone else wrote to convert simple structs to maps. Again, using `reflect` is wading into a deep pool, so it might be a reasonable alternative to use the `bson` hack or hand-written code per struct, or to somehow avoid the conversion to maps if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure - but listen to James. In this case there is no reason to try and do this.

Comment: @elithrar But doesn't mapstructure from github do the opposite of what I want to achieve? `Go library for decoding generic map values into native Go structures`

Comment: @eAbi First line of the README: "mapstructure is a Go library for decoding generic map values to structures and **vice versa**." (emphasis my own)

Comment: @elithrar Yes I saw that. I'm sorry I looked several times on that library but didn't saw that `vice versa`. I looked at it on `godoc` but couldn't see how to convert from struct to map. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I also had need for something like this. I was using an internal package which was converting a struct to a map. I decided to open source it with other `struct` based high level functions. Have a look:

https://github.com/fatih/structs

It has support for:

- Convert struct to a map
- Extract the fields of a struct to a `[]string`
- Extract the values of a struct to a `[]values`
- Check if a struct is initialized or not
- Check if a passed interface is a struct or a pointer to struct

You can see some examples here: http://godoc.org/github.com/fatih/structs#pkg-examples 
For example converting a struct to a map is a simple:

```
type Server struct {
    Name    string
    ID      int32
    Enabled bool
}

s := &Server{
    Name:    "gopher",
    ID:      123456,
    Enabled: true,
}

// => {"Name":"gopher", "ID":123456, "Enabled":true}
m := structs.Map(s)
```

The `structs` package has support for anonymous (embedded) fields and nested structs. The package provides to filter certain fields via field tags.

Comment: The package you provided here is comprehensive and helpful, thank you!

Comment: wow @Fatih Arslan, this is huge. This practically provides "marshalling" structs to `map[string]interface{}`s just like `encoding/json.Marhsal()`, using struct tags and all. Amazing!

Comment: I used this package but I had my struct fields defined with their json/bson field names such as `bson:"_id" json:"_id,omitempty"` and I want those in the final map and not the exported field names used within Go. Is there a solution?

Comment: Here is a way to use "json" tag name instead of the "structs" tag name.
https://github.com/fatih/structs/issues/25

Comment: Just a note that this project is now archived and has no maintenance.

Comment: And I do not want to add another dependency in my project

Comment: Don't forget to export the fields on your struct (Made a noob mistake)

Comment: Any other package that is seen as the replacement? Due to this one being archived?

Comment: @andres Try https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Comment: @Ayala mapstructure  decode maps to structs.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov mapstructure is decoding generic map values to structures *and vice versa*

Answer (score 91):

From `struct` to `map[string]interface{}`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyData struct {
    One   int
    Two   string
    Three int
}

func main() {   
    in := &MyData{One: 1, Two: "second"}

    var inInterface map[string]interface{}
    inrec, _ := json.Marshal(in)
    json.Unmarshal(inrec, &inInterface)

    // iterate through inrecs
    for field, val := range inInterface {
            fmt.Println("KV Pair: ", field, val)
    }
}
```

[go playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/9_U8KTMLB8)

Comment: To keep it more simple, instead of using `var inInterface interface{}`, change it to `var inInterface map[string]interface{}`. See playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/woUiMzL_1X

Comment: Clean and simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks like a hack, I can't find anything clean or simple about this

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. In the resulting map, the int values were converted to float64, that is unexpected behavior.  The inInterface["One"] value will be of type float64 instead of int.

Comment: Marshalling and then unmarshalling seems like a very inefficient way of converting data.

Comment: @d4nyll do you have another solution? Without using reflection (directly) of course.

Comment: It works, but it's not an optimal solution, double encoding is executed, shouldn't be used when performance is critical. About 10 times slower than creating a map and adding key/value manually.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a function I've written in the past to convert a struct to a map, using tags as keys

```
// ToMap converts a struct to a map using the struct's tags.
//
// ToMap uses tags on struct fields to decide which fields to add to the
// returned map.
func ToMap(in interface{}, tag string) (map[string]interface{}, error){
    out := make(map[string]interface{})

    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    // we only accept structs
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ToMap only accepts structs; got %T", v)
    }

    typ := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        // gets us a StructField
        fi := typ.Field(i)
        if tagv := fi.Tag.Get(tag); tagv != "" {
            // set key of map to value in struct field
            out[tagv] = v.Field(i).Interface()
        }
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

Runnable [example here.](http://play.golang.org/p/2Qi3thFf--)

Note, if you have multiple fields with the same tag value, then you will obviously not be able to store them all within a map. It might be prudent to return an error if that happens.

Comment: Hmm, but I think it doesn't work with nested structs, right? I think the struct fields must be traversed recursively.

Comment: Your question didn't mention that. So you want a struct flattened into a map then?

Comment: Yes, a struct flattened into a map (so sub-structures would become a sub-map). You can achieve this by calling the funtion again if the field contains a structure, right?

Comment: I like this, but it is incomplete. It is not considering `"-"` and `",omitempty"`. Other than that it is really good.

Answer (score 14):

I like the importable package for the accepted answer, but it does not translate my json aliases. Most of my projects have a helper function/class that I import.

Here is a function that solves my specific problem.

```golang
// Converts a struct to a map while maintaining the json alias as keys
func StructToMap(obj interface{}) (newMap map[string]interface{}, err error) {
    data, err := json.Marshal(obj) // Convert to a json string

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &newMap) // Convert to a map
    return
}
```

And in the main, this is how it would be called...

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type MyStructObject struct {
    Email string `json:"email_address"`
}

func main() {
    obj := &MyStructObject{Email: "test@test.com"}

    // My solution
    fmt.Println(StructToMap(obj)) // prints {"email_address": "test@test.com"}

    // The currently accepted solution
    fmt.Println(structs.Map(obj)) // prints {"Email": "test@test.com"}
}
```

Comment: It works, but it's not an optimal solution, double encoding is executed, shouldn't be used when performance is critical. About 10 times slower than creating a map and adding key/value manually.

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type bill struct {
    N1 int
    N2 string
    n3 string
}

func main() {
    a := bill{4, "dhfthf", "fdgdf"}

    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)

    values := make(map[string]interface{}, v.NumField())

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if v.Field(i).CanInterface() {
            values[v.Type().Field(i).Name] = v.Field(i).Interface()
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("sorry you have a unexported field (lower case) value you are trying to sneak past. I will not allow it: %v\n", v.Type().Field(i).Name)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(values)

    passObject(&values)
}

func passObject(v1 *map[string]interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("yoyo")
}
```

Comment: this also works for structs coming from different packages. (note you won't have access to unexported fields)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I needed this kind of feature so I wrote this. Can resolve nested structs. By default, uses field names but can also use custom tags. A side effect is that if you set the tagTitle const to json, you could use the json tags you already have.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func StructToMap(val interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    //The name of the tag you will use for fields of struct
    const tagTitle = "kelvin"

    var data map[string]interface{} = make(map[string]interface{})
    varType := reflect.TypeOf(val)
    if varType.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        // Provided value is not an interface, do what you will with that here
        fmt.Println("Not a struct")
        return nil
    }

    value := reflect.ValueOf(val)
    for i := 0; i < varType.NumField(); i++ {
        if !value.Field(i).CanInterface() {
            //Skip unexported fields
            continue
        }
        tag, ok := varType.Field(i).Tag.Lookup(tagTitle)
        var fieldName string
        if ok && len(tag) > 0 {
            fieldName = tag
        } else {
            fieldName = varType.Field(i).Name
        }
        if varType.Field(i).Type.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
            data[fieldName] = value.Field(i).Interface()
        } else {
            data[fieldName] = StructToMap(value.Field(i).Interface())
        }

    }

    return data
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
map := Structpb.AsMap()

// map is the map[string]interface{}
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @FloLie it is pre-define library which will reduce your efforts and will give back your desire response.

Comment: Copy-pasting code is not helpful. Next time leave a explanation as to what the code does, where you found it, and why you chose it over other methods.